# Angular HTML Binding Error with JSON array from Express Subscribe call

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angular

My current setup is this.

1. `ngOnInIt` for my `dashboard.component.ts` runs a `databaseService` call to subscribe to the result.
2. `database.service.ts` run an `http POST` to get data and populate a value `IssuerGroup`.
3. I want to display the result of the `JSON` given to me by my database in HTML.

Code below:

**dashboard.component.ts**

```typescript
import { IssuerGroup } from './../database.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DatabaseService } from '../database.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  issuerGroups: IssuerGroup[];

  constructor(
    private databaseService: DatabaseService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.databaseService.getGroup(id)
      .subscribe(issuerGroups => this.issuerGroups = issuerGroups);
  }
}
```

**database.service.ts**

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

export class IssuerGroup {
  Issuer_Id: number;
  Issuer_Name: string;
  Issuer_Group_Name: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class TeradataService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getGroup(id): Observable<IssuerGroup[]> {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/ig';
    const data = ({
      issuerid: id
    });
    return this._http.post(url, data)
    .pipe(
      map((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return <IssuerGroup[]> res;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```html
<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroups.Issuer_Name }} </p>

<!-- ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Issuer_Name' of undefined -->

<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroup.Issuer_Name }} </p>

<!-- ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Issuer_Name' of undefined -->

<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroups[0].Issuer_Name }} </p>

<!-- this last result produces the following error but the data actually displays on screen correctly -->

<!-- ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined -->
```

**In my last example in the HTML page the data displays but still receive an error.**

**Goal:** Display the result of the JSON I get back from the database in my HTML page with no errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`the safe navigation operator`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) (with `?` before property) while binding variables to your HTML template like:

```
{{ issuerGroups?.Issuer_Name }}
```

It globally says to your view to display `Issuer_Name` **only if** `issuerGroups` exists (is not `null` or `undefined`). The advantage is that you don't have to use `*ngIf` (except some cases) or do further checks if the property exists to display it into your view.

So in your example it will look like:

```
<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroup?.Issuer_Name }} </p>
```

But, in your last binding, since you're calling an index, I suggest you to do like that:

```
<p *ngIf="issuerGroups?.length"> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroups[0]?.Issuer_Name }} </p>
```

or like that:

```
<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroups?.length ? issuerGroups[0]?.Issuer_Name : '' }} </p>
```

But there are so many ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use in your template properties that may not exist yet. Explaining your errors:

```
<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroups.Issuer_Name }} </p>
```

This fails because until the data loads the `issuerGroups` variable is not initialised to any object value and you cannot read properties of the `undefined`, obviously. After the data loads it will not fail, yet it will not display anything too, because the `issuerGroups` gets set to an array type, which does not have `Issuer_Name` field.

```
<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroup.Issuer_Name }} </p>
```

This will always fail because you have no `issuerGroup` field defined at your component at all.

```
<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ issuerGroups[0].Issuer_Name }} </p>
```

This fails before data gets loaded, as the array is not initialized and even if you had initialized it with `[]` it won't have any elements inside and therefore you cannot read the entry at 0 index until there exists one there.

What you should do instead is:

```
<p> Display the Issuer Name here: {{ getIssuerName() }} </p>
```

And adding a method in controller:

```
getIssuerName() {
    if (this.issuerGroups && this.issuerGroups.length > 0) {
        return this.issuerGroups.Issuer_Name[0];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

(of course you may do the check inline in your HTML file, like others suggested, the method is only for code readability)

TL;DR:
Do not access members of objects loaded asynchronously when they are not loaded yet.